# Getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when reading from CSV with JAVA testNG, but why?

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array, testng, dataprovider

When using a dataprovider to read a csv with testcases, I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

The CSV looks like this:

```
TC1;tester@test.com;tester;t;Valid login
TC2;tester@test.com;incorrect;f;Invalid password
TC3;incorrect@test.com;tester;f;Invalid user
TC4;tester@test.com;;fp;Empty password
TC5;;tester;fe;Empty user
```

The Code:

```
package tools;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class DataProviders {

    @DataProvider
    static Object[][] LoginTestInput() throws IOException{

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("src/input/LoginTestInputFile.csv"));
        List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();

        Object[][] returnObject = new Object[myEntries.size()][5];
        for(int i = 1;i<myEntries.size();i++){
            String testCase = myEntries.get(i)[0];
            String username = myEntries.get(i)[1];
            String password = myEntries.get(i)[2];
            String loginSuccessful = myEntries.get(i)[3];
            String description = myEntries.get(i)[4];
            returnObject[i][0] = testCase;
            returnObject[i][1] = username;
            returnObject[i][2] = password;
            returnObject[i][3] = loginSuccessful;
            returnObject[i][4] = description;

        }

        return returnObject;
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
       at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
       at tools.DataProviders.LoginTestInput(DataProviders.java:22)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
   ... 20 more
```

Line 22 in the stacktrace refers to: String testCase = myEntries.get(i)[0];

Comment: myEnteries has its size equal to 0.. print/debug and check...

Answer (score 1):

The exception isnt occurring on the line

```
String testCase = myEntries.get(i)[0];
```

but rather

```
String username = myEntries.get(i)[1];
```

(as shown in the stacktrace) due to the fact that you're using semi-colon characters `;` in the CSV file - only one token is being found for the whole line. OpenCSV's [`CSVReader`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html#CSVReader%28java.io.Reader%29) uses a `,` separator by default. You could use `CSVReader's` overloaded constructor:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("src/input/LoginTestInputFile.csv"), ';');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change like this from

```
for(int i = 1;i<myEntries.size();i++){ ... } to 
for(int i = 0;i<myEntries.size();i++){ ... }
```

Index starts from 0 so.

Also the entry is taken as a line per string array.
Ex: "TC1;tester@test.com;tester;t;Valid login" as a result for

```
String testCase = myEntries.get(i)[0];
```

But inside tat u need to iterate through the string array again.
Better make the file's entries as comma (",") separated instead of semi colon (";"), which will resolve your issues.